# Why searching in array of objects not working?

Tags: javascript

I have the foloowing function:

```
export const filterInputAutocomplete = (arr: any[], control: AbstractControl, looking: string[] = ['value']): any[] => {
    let searchValue = control.value;

    if (!searchValue) {
        return arr.slice();
    }

    return arr.filter(
        (element) =>
            looking.filter(
                (key) =>
                    element[key] &&
                    element[key]
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase() > -1),
            ).length > 0,
    );
};
```

This function accepts `arr` of objects and array `looking` of field names and string value;

I tried to find object in array `arr` where his keys (object) is in `looking` and has `value`.

But I always get empty result. What do I do wrong?

```
let arr = [{"regId": 1}, {"regName": "AAA"}];
let value = '1';
let looking = ['regId'];
```

It should find `[{"regId": 1}]`

Comment: Please post values of ``arr, looking and searchValue``

Comment: Done, I have added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misplaced bracket.

```
.indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase() > -1)
```

Should be:

```
.indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1
```